# How to remove a Gitlab project?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created several repositories in GitLab. One of those was for testing purposes and has some commits and branches. I want to delete or remove this repository. How can I do this?

Answer (score 571, accepted):

1. Go to the **project page**
2. Select "**Settings**"
3. Select the "**General**" section (you must be in the repository you want to delete it)
4. If you have enough rights, then at the bottom of the page will be a button for "**Advanced settings**" (i.e. project settings that may result in data loss) or "**Remove project**" (in newer GitLab versions)
5. Push this button and follow the instructions

This is only available for admins/owner. As a mere project maintainer, you do not see the "Remove project" button.

Comment: I can find the dangerous settings. However when i click it, it folds/unfolds nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Cheers! @0x4a6f4672, I guess! instead of "Dangerous settings"  have changed to "Remove project", worked for me!

Comment: Where is settings ? I can not find it in the project page ><

Comment: @Nikkolasg scroll down the left sidebar

Comment: See the answer from Egon Olieux  below for the new location

Comment: @Nikkolasg Select your repo and go to bottom of your project. You will find "Remove project" button

Comment: I believe now a days "Dangerous Settings" replaced with "Advanced settings". Just expand "Advanced settings" row you will find "Remove Project" button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is now out of date.

Comment: I just created a repository and I want to delete it. I went to https://gitlab.com/matkoniecz/$PROJEST_NAME/settings/repository and I see neither "Advanced settings" or  "Dangerous Settings" Though I am not sure what is "project page" (url example would be nice).

Comment: I believe this is only available to admins. Perhaps that should be mentioned in the answer. I'm a project maintainer and don't have the option.

Comment: Up-until GitLab v14.9 "regular" users could not delete their own projects and had to ask for help from an administrator - see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions

Comment: obs.: need to be owner to this option "settings|general..."

Answer (score 74):

✅ Just at the bottom of your project settings .⚡

New version
[image: new version]

URL : [https://gitlab.com/{USER_NAME}/{PROJECT_NAME}/edit](https://gitlab.com/%7BUSER_NAME%7D/%7BPROJECT_NAME%7D/edit)

- Advanced  : expand
- Remove project

This is only available for admins/owner. As a mere project maintainer, you do not see the "Remove project" button.

Comment: I needed also to expand "General" section (confusingly, not "Repository" section)  after entering settings.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny yeah, not fan of expanding buttons to show more options.

Answer (score 35):

As of June 2016, click the **settings cog** in the top right corner and click **edit project** at the bottom of the list. Then, scroll to the bottom of the page to the **Remove project** section.

This is only available for admins/owner. As a mere project maintainer, you do not see the "Remove project" button.

Comment: I see just a "Rename project" settings. What's wrong?

Comment: NOTE: As of January 2017 the "settings cog" only shows if your browser window is at least 992px wide. (their responsive design hides it via media queries with windows sizes narrower than that. I think this is just an oversight . I'll report it to them)

Comment: Also no "Remove project" for me. I only see "rename project". I am the master of the project.

Answer (score 26):

Goto

```
Setting->General
```

Scroll then you can see the last option "`Advanced`" click on the (Expand). click on the "`Delete Project`"

[image]

Comment: Where I can see settings with section "Dangerous settings"? Can you give example of an URL?

Comment: Go in setting->advance(expand)->removeproject

Comment: @HarsukhMakwana Thanks for the masterful screen shot!

Answer (score 18):

To remove a project, you have to be the owner of this project, or the administrator of gitlab. Otherwise you can only see "rename project" but no "remove project".

NOTE THAT: the creator project is NOT always the owner of the project. If the project is in a project-group, and the project-group is created by another one, then the owner is the creator of the project-group by default.

You can find the owner's name of the project in the page Settings -> Members.

Answer (score 12):

This is taken from feb 2018

Follow the following test

1. Gitlab Home Page
2. Select your projects button under Projects Menus
3. Click your desired project
4. Select Settings (from left sidebar)
5. Click Advanced settings
6. Click Remove Project

**Or Click the following Link**

Note : USER_NAME will replace by your username

PROJECT_NAME will replace by your repository name

https://gitlab.com/USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/edit

click Expand under Advanced settings portion

Click remove project bottom of the page

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As of September 2017,
1. Click on your project.
2. Select setting on the top most corner.
3. Scroll down the page and click on expand in front of advance setting.
4. Scroll down the page and click on the Remove Project button.
5. Type your project name in text box and click on confirm.

Comment: they moved it again.  settings is on the left pane on the very bottom.  i just deleted my gitlab account because of this.  seems they're trying to hide these important operations.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open project
2. Setting (In the left sidebar)
3. General
4. Advanced Setting (Click on Expand)
5. Remove Project (Bottom of the Page)
6. Confirm (By typing project name and press Confirm button)

Answer (score 6):

As of October 2017:
1. In the list of your projects, click on the project you want to delete;
2. In the left sidebar, click on the 'Setting' button;
3. Locate the 'Advanced settings' section and click on the related 'Expand' button;
4. At the bottom you'll find the 'Remove Project' button, click it;
5. Type the name of the project inside the text input and Confirm.

Answer (score 5):

As per January 13,2018
Do as follow:

1. Click on Project you want to delete.
2. Click **Setting** on right buttom corner.
3. Locate the **Advanced settings** section and click on the  '**Expand**' button
4. Then Scroll down the page and click on the **Remove Project** button.
5. Type your project name. **Note : Removed project CANNOT be restored!** and click on confirm.
6. Then project will be deleted and soon 404 page error will be displayed for that project.

Comment: Typing my project name wont enable the delete button.

Answer (score 4):

1. goto **Settings -> General**

[image]

2. scroll down to **Advanced** & click **Expand** button
   [image]
3. after clicking expand button , **scroll down to bottom of the page**
   [image]
4. Click **Delete Project** Red Button , a popup will show up
   [image]
5. **Type your Project Repository name** and **Click Yes Delete Project button**

Comment: What is the problem when I don't have `Settings` below `Snippets` ?

Answer (score 3):

Click on Project settings which you want to delete-->General project settings-->Expand-->Advanced settings-->Remove project.

Answer (score 2):

- Click on the Project you want to delete.
- Click Setting in the right bottom corner.
- click general then go to advance
- than remove the project

Answer (score 2):

2022 Update:

https://gitlab.com/dashboard/projects

Be on to be deleted Project page >> Settings >> General >> Advanced >> Delete project

It will ask for the confirmation of the project name and once entered, choose - "yes, delete"

The user must have privileges to do so!

Answer (score 1):

It is hidden in Setting menu, section `general` (not `repository`!) at `https://gitlab.com/$USER_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME/edit`and it again hidden in a section "Advance settings"- you need to click a "expand" button.

Answer (score 1):

- 1.Gitlab Home Page
- 2.Select your projects button under Projects Menus
- 3.Click your desired project
- 4.Select Settings (from left sidebar)
- 5.Click Advanced settings Expand the Advanced settings this will be middle of the page
- 6.Click Remove
- 7.Project In the Modal write your project name

Hope you can Successfully remove your project. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For the *2021* Gitlab version

1. Go to the **project page**.
   URL look like this. `https://gitlab.com/<username>/<project name>`
2. Select **"Settings"** in the left sidebar
3. Select the **"General"** section (you must be in the repository you want to delete to delete it)
4. If you have enough rights, then at the bottom of the page will be the section named **"Advanced"**. Then Click the **"Expand"** button.
5. Scroll down in the **"Advanced"** section, then Click the **"Delete project"** button.
6. Put and confirm the repository name in the popup, then Click the **"Yes, delete project"** button.

Answer (score 0):

click on the icon "admin area"
click on the link "project[number]"
click on the button Delete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wquwY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5n2x.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, using the gitlab API v4, you can delete a project with the following curl request:

```bash
curl -X DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <personal-access-token>" https://<gitlab-host>/api/v4/projects/<project-id>
```

Where:

- `personal-access-token` is generated on the **User settings**/**Access tokens** page with `api` scope,
- `gitlab-host` is Your self-hosted gitlab domain or `gitlab.com`,
- `project-id` is at the top of the frontpage of your repository.

If successful request You should see the following response:

```json
{"message":"202 Accepted"}
```