# How to delete a Gitlab repository

Tags: git, user-interface, gitlab

I have googled a while now and could not find a solution that fits the current UI of Gitlab. I am trying to remove a repository I previously created on Gitlab. I navigate to **edit project** by clicking the settings cog on the right. After scrolling down to the bottom I can not find a section called **remove project**. Instead, I only see **rename project**. I should have the proper rights because I am the master of the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a Gitlab project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032232/how-to-remove-a-gitlab-project)

Answer (score 42):

Go to **Settings** > Expand **Advanced Settings** > **Remove Project**

[image: Remove Project from GitLab]

Answer (score 8):

It seems like **master** privilege is not sufficient. An **owner** privilege is required to perform such actions.

Comment: Yeah, GitLab has "improved" UI in such a way that some basic workflows are now confusing for no good reason.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open project
2. Setting (In the left sidebar)
3. General
4. Advanced Setting (Click on Expand)
5. Remove Project (Bottom of the Page)
6. Confirm (By typing project name and press Confirm button)

Answer (score 1):

1. open project
2. Settings
3. General section
4. Expand Advanced Settings

finally Remove

Answer (score 1):

(Most) of the other answers work.

**But:** When you are are running a self-hosted gitlab they are ****not** complete**.
The repo will not deleted, but **only marked as deleted and hidden**.

The full solution:
*(This is for gitlab 14.8.4, other versions might have some tiny differences)*

**First let the site forget about it:**

1. Open the project on your gitlab site
2. Navigate to: *Settings > General*
3. Click *Expand* next to the *Advanced* section
4. At the bottom of the page choose *Delete project*

**Gitlab will mark it as deleted and after a couple of minutes a part, *but not everything*, will be "really" deleted.**

**After waiting a couple of minutes delete everything that has not been completely deleted:**

1. Open a terminal and search the first 4 hexadecimal chars of the git repo:
   `find /var/opt/gitlab/ | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if(/^.*hashed\/(.{5}).*\+deleted\.git$/)' | sort | uniq`
   *(Let's assume the output is `e6/29` for example)*
2. Double-check if you don't have another repo that starts with the same 4 chars:
   `ls /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/+gitaly/state/@hashed/e6/29`
   *(Every line should contain the same long hexadecimal string)*
3. Delete everything gitlab didn't delete yet:
   *(Some of the dirs might not exist. It depends on how you create your project)*

```
rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/+gitaly/state/@hashed/e6/29
rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/e6/29
rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/tmp/gitlab_exports/@hashed/e6/29
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open repository
2. Click 'Settings'
3. Select 'Options' (if it is not already selected)
4. Scroll down the page to 'Danger zone'
5. Click 'Delete this repository'
6. Follow the instructions.